# Firabase Functions deploy had errors

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I'm trying to deploy my app to firebase but every time give me this issue but I don't know what is it need !?

this is my code in app.js

```
//construct
const functions     = require("firebase-functions")
const express       = require('express');
const app           = express();
const path          = require('path');
const bodyParser    = require('body-parser');
const cors          = require('cors');
const config        = require('./config');
//const port          = config.port;

//initialize
app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'../public')));

const books= require('./routes/books');
app.use('/books', books);

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app)

//start server code
// app.listen(port, ()=> {
//     console.log('node serve has been started on port : '+port);
// })
```

> - functions: Finished running predeploy script. i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
> - functions: all necessary APIs are enabled i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading... i  functions: packaged functions
>     (57.1 KB) for uploading
> - functions: functions folder uploaded successfully i  hosting[angular6test-1c758]: beginning deploy... i 
>     hosting[angular6test-1c758]: found 68 files in public
> - hosting[angular6test-1c758]: file upload complete i  functions: updating Node.js 6 function app(us-central1)... ! 
>     functions[app(us-central1)]: Deployment error. Build failed: exit
>     status 1
>
> > canvas@2.4.1 install /workspace/node_modules/canvas
> >     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
>
> node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download
>   node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404):
>   https://github.com/node-gfx/node-canvas-prebuilt/releases/download/v2.4.1/canvas-v2.4.1-node-v48-linux-glibc-x64.tar.gz
>   node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for canvas@2.4.1 and
>   node@6.16.0 (node-v48 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with
>   node-gyp) /bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found gyp: Call to 'pkg-config
>   pixman-1 --libs' returned exit status 127 while in binding.gyp. while
>   trying to load binding.gyp gyp ERR! configure error gyp ERR! stack
>   Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1 gyp ERR! stack     at
>   ChildProcess.onCpExit
>   (/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:305:16)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13) gyp ERR! stack     at
>   ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7) gyp ERR! stack     at
>   Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:219:12)
>   gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-1028-gcp gyp ERR! command
>   "/nodejs/bin/node"
>   "/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
>   "configure" "--fallback-to-build"
>   "--module=/workspace/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node"
>   "--module_name=canvas"
>   "--module_path=/workspace/node_modules/canvas/build/Release"
>   "--napi_version=3" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0"
>   "--node_napi_label=node-v48" gyp ERR! cwd
>   /workspace/node_modules/canvas gyp ERR! node -v v6.16.0 gyp ERR!
>   node-gyp -v v3.4.0 gyp ERR! not ok node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/nodejs/bin/node
>   /nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js
>   configure --fallback-to-build
>   --module=/workspace/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/workspace/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v48' (1) node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.
>   (/workspace/node_modules/canvas/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13) node-pre-gyp
>   ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7) node-pre-gyp
>   ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:920:16)
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (internal/child_process.js:230:5) node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux
>   4.15.0-1028-gcp node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/nodejs/bin/node" "/workspace/node_modules/canvas/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp"
>   "install" "--fallback-to-build" node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd
>   /workspace/node_modules/canvas node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v6.16.0
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0 node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
>   Failed to execute '/nodejs/bin/node
>   /nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js
>   configure --fallback-to-build
>   --module=/workspace/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/workspace/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v48' (1) aa14@0.0.1 /workspace `-- merge-images@1.1.0
>
> npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-1028-gcp npm ERR! argv "/nodejs/bin/node"
>   "/nodejs/bin/npm" "--global-style" "--production" "--fetch-retries=5"
>   "--fetch-retry-factor=2" "--fetch-retry-mintimeout=1000" "install"
>   "/workspace" npm ERR! node v6.16.0 npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10 npm ERR!
>   code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! canvas@2.4.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install
>   --fallback-to-build` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the canvas@2.4.1 install script 'node-pre-gyp install
>   --fallback-to-build'. npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed. npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely
>   a problem with the canvas package, npm ERR! not with npm itself. npm
>   ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system: npm ERR!
>   node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build npm ERR! You can get
>   information on how to open an issue for this project with: npm ERR!
>   npm bugs canvas npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their
>   info via: npm ERR!     npm owner ls canvas npm ERR! There is likely
>   additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     /workspace/npm-debug.log
>
> Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
>           app
>
> To try redeploying those functions, run:
>       firebase deploy --only functions:app
>
> To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
>       firebase deploy --except functions
>
> Error: Functions did not deploy properly.

**

### I Found the answer

**

firebase deploy using node 6 as default
add `"engines": { "node": "8" }` to upgrade the node

Comment: Any defined? I'm using 8.12.0 and still have an issue with 

    npm ERR! canvas@2.4.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`


node-gyp version: 3.8.0

Comment: do you doing deploy by firebase !? or what do you do ?

Comment: I'm installing (or trying to installl) npm i chartjs-node-canvas, so no exactly, the same what you did

Comment: try to downgrade the canvas to 2.3.1  but which node version on your device ?

Comment: The same error with canvas 2.3.1, node js: 8.12.0. Now I see that:npm@6.4.1 C:\...Roaming\nvm\v8.12.0\node_modules\npm, so still node 6.4.1 is in use. I need to reconfigure this. Maybe this will be a solution.

Comment: yes i faced this issue and solved it by force firebase used node 8 instead 6 , let me search for this